# Retrieve artifact from a githiub project?

Tags: android, maven, github

is there a way to retrieve just the artefact from a GitHub project that has its own pom such as this project:

https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker

I know that i could always checkout the code and do a mvn install myself but i was wondering if i can avoid that all and just treat it as if the project was hosted in the official Maven central repository where you do not need to retrieve and checkout the src code and simply add a dependency property in your pom file pointing to that artefact that is stored in maven central.

Possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, I am afraid there is no other way except running `git clone` and `mvn install` by yourself. All artifacts has to be in some repository like Maven repo or JBoss repo. Btw this project you want to build looks like to be in [Maven central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.simonvt/android-numberpicker):-)